# Inconsistent Behaviour Between 2 Players of Game

Tags: c++, winapi, window, gdi

I've been making a game for an English presentation (I know right?) and I've been having a few weird problems recently.

At this stage, there are two squares for the players that can fire bullets. When the bullets hit the side of the screen or the middle border, they should disappear and possibly be reused later.

The problem is, first of all, when either player shoots up or down, the bullets disappear into the top/bottom/middle of the screen like they're supposed to. If player 2 shoots a few to the side, as soon as one hits, they seem to all disappear (only player 2's bullets) and I have to wait a few seconds before it starts shooting again.

The main problem though, is that even when I use the exact same code modified for player 1 instead of player 2, when player 1's first shot to hit the side of the screen gets there, it segfaults the program.

The REALLY odd thing is that at one point, this happened, and without changing anything, I ran it again and it all worked perfectly fine. It might have to do with the order of bullets between player 1 and 2, or even where I shoot first. I've tried recreating it, but no results yet.

Just a note before you try to compile the code, I used a wrapper I made to make the window with ease. I noted down what goes on behind the scenes with /// comments though, so adding that info into whatever method you use to make your windows will work just as well.

Problem areas are listed near the bottom:

```
///Works best on 1280x1024 resolution
///1 vs 1 splitscreen game that involves flying around and shooting things
///angles start at 0 facing upwards and increase clockwise

#include <window.h> //incomplete wrapper, but works perfectly for quick, easy window creation
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES //for M_PI
#include <cmath> //for M_PI

#include <iostream> //used for debugging
using std::cout; //output

struct Actions //actions a player can take
{
    bool up; //if player is moving in these 4 directions, they will be true
    bool left;
    bool down;
    bool right;
    bool shoot; //if player is shooting, this will be true
};

struct Player //a player
{
    Player() {};

    void fire(); //fire a bullet
    void checkActions (HWND); //check what actions player is taking

    double x; //position (centre of square)
    double y;
    double angle; //angle (might add diagonals so...)
    int pnum; //player number (0 or 1)
    COLORREF colour; //player's colour
    Actions action; //player's actions
};

struct Bullet //a bullet
{
    double x; //position (centre of square)
    double y;
    Player owner; //owner of bullet
    int index; //bullet's index in array
    double angle; //bullet's angle
};

Player *p = new Player[2]; //2 players
Bullet **bullet; //2d array of bullets

int bcount[2] = {0}; //number of bullets for each player
int btime [2] = {0}; //timer for bullets

const double PLSIZE = 10; //player size = 20x20 square (10 from centre outwards)
const double BSIZE = 2; //bullet size = 4x4 square
const double SPEED = 1; //player's moving speed is 1
const int BDELAY = 100; //delay between bullets is 100ms

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM); //window procedure
void OnPaint (HDC, HWND); //painting function
void moveBullets (HWND); //calculates bullet positions
void deleteBullet (int, int); //"deletes" a bullet

int main() //main function
{
    //hide(console()); //hides console window (currently showing for debugging)

    bullet = new Bullet*[2]; //create bullet array of 1000/player (I'll size down the 1000 later)
    bullet[0] = new Bullet[1000];
    bullet[1] = new Bullet[1000];

    p[0].x = 630; //player 1's position
    p[0].y = 250;
    p[0].colour = RGB(255,0,0); //player 1 is red
    p[0].pnum = 0; //player 1's number is 0
    p[0].angle = 0; //face upwards
    p[0].action = {0}; //player 1 is doing nothing

    p[1].x = 630; //player 2's position
    p[1].y = 750;
    p[1].colour = RGB(0,0,255); //player 2 is blue
    p[1].pnum = 1; //player 2's number is 1
    p[1].angle = 0; //face upwards
    p[1].action = {0}; //player 2 is doing nothing

    Window window; //create window object (part of wrapper, sets default values for class and window)

    ///background = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW
    ///class name = "Default Wrapper Class"
    ///hInstance = GetModuleHandle (NULL)
    ///all others are standard default or 0

    window.createClass(WndProc); //create class using earlier-mentioned window procedure

    window.setStyle(WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_MAXIMIZE); //set window style to overlapped and maximized
    window.setTitle (L"Word Blaster"); //set window title to "Word Blaster" (it's an English project, shush)

    ///x/y/width/height = CW_USEDEFAULT
    ///class name = other class name
    ///hInstance = GetModuleHandle (NULL)
    ///all others are standard default or 0

    HWND hwnd = window.createWindow(); //create window

    MSG msg; //message loop

    while(GetMessage(&msg,0,0,0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) //window proc
{
    HDC hdc; //hdc for painting
    PAINTSTRUCT ps; //paintstruct for painting
    bool ret = false; //return value (you'll see later)

    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE: //currently not in use

            break;

        case WM_KEYDOWN: //check for pressed keys
            switch (wParam) //keycode
            {
                case 0x57: //'w'
                    p[0].action.up = true; //player 1 wants to move up (couldn't just change position here or no diagonal movement)
                    break;

                case 0x41: //'a', left
                    p[0].action.left = true;
                    break;

                case 0x53: //'s', down
                    p[0].action.down = true;
                    break;

                case 0x44: //'d', right
                    p[0].action.right = true;
                    break;

                case 0x20: // space, shoot
                    p[0].action.shoot = true;
                    break;

                case VK_UP: //up arrow, player 2 up
                    p[1].action.up = true;
                    break;

                case VK_LEFT: //left arrow
                    p[1].action.left = true;
                    break;

                case VK_DOWN: //down arrow
                    p[1].action.down = true;
                    break;

                case VK_RIGHT: //right arrow
                    p[1].action.right = true;
                    break;

                case VK_RETURN: //either enter key, p2 shoot
                    p[1].action.shoot = true;
                    break;
            }

            break;

        case WM_KEYUP: //check for unpressed keys
            switch (wParam)
            {
                case 0x57: //'w', player 1 should stop moving up
                    p[0].action.up = false;
                    break;

                case 0x41: //all same order as above
                    p[0].action.left = false;
                    break;

                case 0x53:
                    p[0].action.down = false;
                    break;

                case 0x44:
                    p[0].action.right = false;
                    break;

                case 0x20: // space
                    p[0].action.shoot = false;
                    break;

                case VK_UP:
                    p[1].action.up = false;
                    break;

                case VK_LEFT:
                    p[1].action.left = false;
                    break;

                case VK_DOWN:
                    p[1].action.down = false;
                    break;

                case VK_RIGHT:
                    p[1].action.right = false;
                    break;

                case VK_RETURN:
                    p[1].action.shoot = false;
                    break;
            }

            break;

        case WM_PAINT: //draw on screen
            hdc = BeginPaint (hwnd, &ps); //prepare window for drawing
            OnPaint (hdc,hwnd); //draw
            EndPaint (hwnd, &ps); //finish drawing
            break;

        case WM_CLOSE: //if ready to close
            show(console()); //show console window in case it doesn't close
            end(); //close console window (PostMessage (GetConsoleWindow(),WM_CLOSE,0,0))
            DestroyWindow(hwnd); //close main window
            break;

        case WM_DESTROY: //window is closing
            PostQuitMessage(0); //post WM_QUIT to end (probably won't get here since console closes earlier)
            break;

        case WM_ERASEBKGND: //if background is going to be erased, don't let it (causes flicker)
            ret = true; //hold that thought for a bit
            break;
}

p[0].checkActions(hwnd); //check player 1's actions
p[1].checkActions(hwnd); //check player 2's actions
moveBullets (hwnd); //move any bullets
InvalidateRect (hwnd,NULL,true); //update window
Sleep (1); //delay a bit

if (!ret) return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam); //if WM_ERASEBKGND wasn't called, take default action
}

void Player::fire() //fire a bullet
{
    bullet [pnum][bcount[pnum]].x = x; //bullet starts in player's centre
    bullet [pnum][bcount[pnum]].y = y;
    bullet [pnum][bcount[pnum]].owner = *this; //owner of bullet is the object calling this function
    bullet [pnum][bcount[pnum]].index = bcount[pnum]; //index of bullet is the number of bullets for player
    bullet [pnum][bcount[pnum]].angle = angle; //angle of bullet is player's angle

    while (
              (bullet[pnum][bcount[pnum]].x - BSIZE < x + PLSIZE && bullet[pnum][bcount[pnum]].x - BSIZE > x - PLSIZE //left side of bullet inside player OR
           || bullet[pnum][bcount[pnum]].x + BSIZE < x + PLSIZE && bullet[pnum][bcount[pnum]].x + BSIZE > x - PLSIZE) //right side in player --- AND ---
           && (bullet[pnum][bcount[pnum]].y - BSIZE < y + PLSIZE && bullet[pnum][bcount[pnum]].y - BSIZE > y - PLSIZE //top in player OR
           || bullet[pnum][bcount[pnum]].y + BSIZE < y + PLSIZE && bullet[pnum][bcount[pnum]].y + BSIZE > y - PLSIZE) //bottom in player
           )
           {
               bullet[pnum][bcount[pnum]].x += sin (bullet[pnum][bcount[pnum]].angle * M_PI / 180); //start moving bullet until it's out
               bullet[pnum][bcount[pnum]].y -= cos (bullet[pnum][bcount[pnum]].angle * M_PI / 180);
           }

    btime [pnum] = GetTickCount(); //set up bullet delay for that player
    ++bcount[pnum]; //increase number of bullets for that player
}

void Player::checkActions (HWND hwnd) //check player's actions
{
    RECT r;
    GetClientRect (hwnd, &r); //get canvas space

    if (action.up) //if moving up
    {
        y -= SPEED; //change y position
       angle = 0; //change angle

        if (pnum == 0) //if player 1
        {
            if (y - PLSIZE < 1) y = PLSIZE + 1; //check top of screen boundary
        }

        else //if player 2
        {
            if (y - PLSIZE < r.bottom / 2 + 5) y = r.bottom / 2 + 5 + PLSIZE; //check middle boundary
        }
    }

    if (action.left) //if moving left
    {
        x -= SPEED; //change x position
        angle = 270; //change angle
        if (x - PLSIZE < 1) x = PLSIZE + 1; //check left of screen boundary
    }

    if (action.down) //down is opposite of up
    {
        y += SPEED;
        angle = 180;

        if (pnum == 0)
        {
            if (y + PLSIZE > r.bottom / 2 - 5) y = r.bottom / 2 - 5 - PLSIZE;
        }

        else
        {
            if (y + PLSIZE > r.bottom) y = r.bottom - PLSIZE;
        }
    }

    if (action.right) //right is opposite of left
    {
        x += SPEED;
        angle = 90;
        if (x + PLSIZE > r.right) x = r.right - PLSIZE;
    }

    if (action.shoot && GetTickCount() - btime [pnum] > BDELAY) fire(); //if player wants to shoot and enough time has passed, fire bullet
}

void OnPaint (HDC hdc, HWND hwnd) //draw stuff
{
    RECT r;
    GetClientRect (hwnd, &r); //get canvas area

    HDC buffer = CreateCompatibleDC (hdc); //create buffer DC
    HBITMAP bitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap (hdc,r.right,r.bottom); //create buffer bitmap
    HBITMAP oldBM = (HBITMAP)SelectObject (buffer, bitmap); //create another bitmap

    HBRUSH player1brush = CreateSolidBrush(p[0].colour); //player 1's brush
    HBRUSH player2brush = CreateSolidBrush(p[1].colour); //player 2's brush
    HBRUSH blackBrush = CreateSolidBrush (RGB(0,0,0)); //black brush
    HPEN /*player1*/pen = CreatePen (PS_NULL,1,RGB(255,0,0)); //don't need pen

    BitBlt(buffer,0,0,r.right,r.bottom,NULL,0,0,WHITENESS); //erase bitmap background

    SelectObject(buffer,pen); //select pen (since I need one to do anything)

    SelectObject (buffer, blackBrush); //select black brush
    Rectangle (buffer, 0, r.bottom / 2 - 5, r.right, r.bottom / 2 + 5); //draw middle line

//    MoveTo () //these comments are because I was about to change the graphics to ships

    SelectObject (buffer,player1brush); //select player 1's brush
    Rectangle (buffer,p[0].x-PLSIZE,p[0].y-PLSIZE,p[0].x+PLSIZE,p[0].y+PLSIZE); //draw player 1

    SelectObject (buffer,player2brush); //do the same for p2
    Rectangle (buffer,p[1].x-PLSIZE,p[1].y-PLSIZE,p[1].x+PLSIZE,p[1].y+PLSIZE);

    if (bcount[0] > 0) //if p1 has a bullet
    {
        SelectObject (buffer, blackBrush); //select black brush

        for (int i = 0; i < bcount[0]; ++i) //draw bullet(s)
        {
            Ellipse (buffer, bullet [0][i].x - BSIZE, bullet [0][i].y - BSIZE, bullet [0][i].x + BSIZE, bullet [0][i].y + BSIZE);
        }
    }

    if (bcount[1] > 0) //same goes for p2
    {
        SelectObject (buffer, blackBrush);

        for (int i = 0; i < bcount[1]; ++i)
        {
            Ellipse (buffer, bullet [1][i].x - BSIZE, bullet [1][i].y - BSIZE, bullet [1][i].x + BSIZE, bullet [1][i].y + BSIZE);
        }
    }

    BitBlt(hdc, 0,0, r.right , r.bottom, buffer, 0,0, SRCCOPY); //copy buffer bitmap to window

    DeleteObject (player1brush); //delete stuff
    DeleteObject (player2brush);
    DeleteObject (pen);
    SelectObject (buffer, oldBM);
    DeleteObject (bitmap);
    DeleteDC(buffer);
}

void moveBullets (HWND hwnd) //move the bullets ***PROBLEM AREA***
{
    RECT r;
    GetClientRect (hwnd, &r); //get canvas area

    if (bcount[0] > 0) //if p1 has bullet(s)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < bcount[0]; ++i) //go through p1's bullets
        {
            ///DOESN'T WORK
            bullet [0][i].x += sin (bullet [0][i].angle * M_PI / 180); //move the bullet horizontally
            if (bullet [0][i].x - BSIZE < 1 || bullet [0][i].x + BSIZE > r.right) //if out of bounds
            {
                deleteBullet (0, bullet [0][i].index); //delete the bullet
                --i; //if bullet [2] was deleted, bullet [2] will now be the old bullet [3] so recheck this one next time
            }

            ///WORKS PERFECTLY
            bullet [0][i].y -= cos (bullet [0][i].angle * M_PI / 180); //do same for y, including middle border
            if (bullet [0][i].y - BSIZE < 1 || bullet [0][i].y + BSIZE > r.bottom / 2 - 5)
            {
                deleteBullet (0, bullet [0][i].index);
                --i;
            }
        }
    }

    if (bcount[1] > 0) //exact same thing (I checked a LOT) for p2
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < bcount[1]; ++i)
        {
            ///WORKS PERFECTLY (at least in the p1 sense, there is a slight problem)
            bullet [1][i].x += sin (bullet [1][i].angle * M_PI / 180);
            if (bullet [1][i].x - BSIZE < 1 || bullet [1][i].x + BSIZE > r.right)
            {
                deleteBullet (1, bullet [1][i].index);
                --i;
            }

            ///WORKS PERFECTLY
            bullet [1][i].y -= cos (bullet [1][i].angle * M_PI / 180);
            if (bullet [1][i].y - BSIZE < r.bottom / 2 + 5 || bullet [1][i].y + BSIZE > r.bottom)
            {
                deleteBullet (1, bullet [1][i].index);
                --i;
            }
        }
    }
}

void deleteBullet (int player, int index) //delete bullet ***PROBLEM AREA***
{
    if (index != bcount [player] - 1) //if it isn't the last bullet
    {
        for (int j = index; j < bcount[player] - 1; ++j) //go from here to the end of the current bullets - 1
        {
            bullet [player][j] = bullet [player][j+1]; //copy the next bullet into this spot
            --bullet [player][j].index; //change the index of the bullet since it was moved back one
        }
    }

    --bcount [player]; //lessen the bullet count, this is all that's needed if it's the last bullet
}
```

Any help with said problems or with something else you notice would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: one side thing I forgot to ask was if there was a better way to continuously do things like move bullets for example than to put all that outside of the switch in the window procedure and the `DefWindowProc` after it.

Comment: #include <window.h> not found.. if not big, post that too.. And I suggest you rename it to my_window.h

Comment: also how have you been debugging this code without a single printf or cout?!

Comment: A simple container (for the bullets) and some object for players would save you a lot of trouble. I've definitely been there before, just trying to get something done and copying code, but when something isn't working, it can be maddening! Right? : )

Comment: @thekashyap I know I wasn't too creative with the name, and lots of the things are 0 or default (eg. LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);) minus the hInstance, which is GetModuleHandle (NULL), the class name (as if it matters), the title (as if *that* matters) and the style (WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_MAXIMIZE)

Comment: @thekashyap (again) My debugging is way under par, I'm sure, because I cout what variables are connected with my problem, and then erase it all when it's fixed. It also lengthened the code even more so I took it out as it's definitely nothing to do with the problem

Comment: @Oliver True, it probably would save a lot of trouble, and I usually end up doing something different every time I make something. It opens up possibilities for a style I like best, but I did have a reasonable idea of approximately what each section would be like. The thing I'm concerned about is that player 2 and player 1 have different results when their bullets reach the horizontal edges of the screen. It's quite unpredictable considering almost the exact same code is used for each.

Comment: It's not too often that the debug log/traces are part of the problem, but that's not the point, you should add the logs and see what's happening before you post "full" code here. "my_" is not a creative prefix. :)

Comment: Well, the truth is that I have never actually used a debugger. All of my debugging is done realtime while I run the program. I guess I never bothered to learn how to use the C::B debugger and whenever I was actually debugging I figured outputting information would be faster for the current program, even if it wasn't overall. Anyways, I guess keeping track of bullet[0/1][i]'s x and y values would've helped somewhat if I picked up on the fact that they were inconsistent. I really did look over it for quite a while trying different things before posting it, and did mention the "problem" areas.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `deleteBullet` may get called twice on the same `i` inside the loop `for (i=0...)` in moveBullets. I think this could happen if the bullet is moving diagonally. I'm not sure it's the cause of the trouble, though.

First English question I've seen on stackoverflow!

Comment: I looked at the function, and while it's definitely not diagonal movement (as there is no bullet diagonal movement at the moment), you bring up a valid point considering decrementing i could affect the y portion. I'll get back to you on that.

Comment: Okay, after a tiny bit of testing following putting x and y into separate for loops, it seems to be working. Indeed deleting a bullet in the x portion would not interfere with the y portion later on now. I'll be adding and testing over the weekend so if I see no more trace of either problem by tomorrow, I'll mark this as answered. The real kicker is that this computer is like 100x slower than the one I'll be presenting on >.>